# DateEntry.set_date(datetime.date.min) setting it to 2001-01-01 (tkcalendar)

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter, tkcalendar

I have a DateEntry widget that when the user doesn't input a text i set DateEntry to a default date of datetime.date.min

The problem is that for some reason when i set the date from the DateEntry it returns 2001-01-01 instead of the min date of datetime.

If theres no input i want the date to be either blank, null, or some date that doesnt interfere in a database.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
import datetime

windows = Tk()
windows.geometry("500x200")

def getdate():
    if(doc_value.get()==''):
        fecha_doc_cal.set_date(datetime.date.min)
        print(fecha_doc_cal.get_date())
    
    #Testing different date formats
    if(doc_value.get()==''):
        fecha_doc_cal.set_date(datetime.date(1700,1,1))
        print(fecha_doc_cal.get_date())
        return 0

doc_value = StringVar()

doc_en = Entry(windows, textvariable=doc_value)
doc_en.grid(row=12, column=4, padx=10, pady=5)

fecha_doc_cal = DateEntry(windows,width=17,bg="darkblue",fg="white",year=2022)
fecha_doc_cal._set_text("Choose a Date")
fecha_doc_cal.grid(row=12, column=5, padx=10, pady=5)

send = Button(windows, text="Send", command=getdate)
send.grid(row=18, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

windows.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the min date of datetime you expect

Comment: Then set the default date of the `DateEntry` to whatever you want it to be.